# spark scala get uncommon map elements

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark

I am trying to split my data set into train and test data sets. I first read the file into memory as shown here:

```
val ratings = sc.textFile(movieLensdataHome+"/ratings.csv").map { line=>
  val fields = line.split(",")
  Rating(fields(0).toInt,fields(1).toInt,fields(2).toDouble)
}
```

Then I select 80% of those for my training set:

```
val train = ratings.sample(false,.8,1)
```

Is there an easy way to get the test set in a distributed way,
I am trying this but fails:

```
val test = ratings.filter(!_.equals(train.map(_)))
```

Comment: The key misunderstanding in the question is the use of the function 'map' in your filter.  'map' is the transformation of one value to another value specified by the given function.  What you may be thinking about is looking up a value in a hashmap, but this is misunderstanding the definition of the map function.

Answer (score 3):

```
val test = ratings.subtract(train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here. http://markmail.org/message/qi6srcyka6lcxe7o

Here is the code

```
  def split[T : ClassManifest](data: RDD[T], p: Double, seed: Long =
System.currentTimeMillis): (RDD[T], RDD[T]) = {
    val rand = new java.util.Random(seed)
    val partitionSeeds = data.partitions.map(partition => rand.nextLong)
    val temp = data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) => {
      val partitionRand = new java.util.Random(partitionSeeds(index))
      iter.map(x => (x, partitionRand.nextDouble))

    })
    (temp.filter(_._2 <= p).map(_._1), temp.filter(_._2 > p).map(_._1))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an exclusion method (like filter or subtract), I'd partition the set "by hand" for a more efficient execution:

```
val probabilisticSegment:(RDD[Double,Rating],Double=>Boolean) => RDD[Rating] = 
    (rdd,prob) => rdd.filter{case (k,v) => prob(k)}.map {case (k,v) => v}

val ranRating = rating.map( x=> (Random.nextDouble(), x)).cache
val train = probabilisticSegment(ranRating, _ < 0.8)
val test = probabilisticSegment(ranRating, _ >= 0.8)
```

`cache` saves the intermediate RDD sothat the next two operations can be performed from that point on without incurring in the execution of the complete lineage.

(*) Note the use of `val` to define a function instead of `def`. `val`s are serializer-friendly

Comment: I am having trouble executing probabilisticSegment. In `{case (k,v) => v` where does the `}` end ? still learning scala duck typing.

Comment: should be: `{case (k,v) => v}`. Edited the code to reflect that.